# R - using a variable to pass column filter conditions to select from data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to use a variable that can contain dynamically generated column filter conditions to subset from a data frame. 
   This is situation:
1) data is a data frame with columns as shown

```
   Symbol Yield    PE DivGrowth  
1    ABBV  3.46 18.80      5.00  
2     ABM  2.24 21.18      3.33  
3     ABT  2.26 23.65     10.85  
4     ADM  1.91 22.29      9.08  
5     ADP  2.46 25.83      8.57  
6     AFL  2.25  9.26      5.97  
7     ALB  1.44 13.53     13.15  
8    ANDE  1.02 19.59      5.74  
9     AOS  1.29 25.11      9.99  
10    APD  2.41 25.08      2.53  
11   ARLP  5.50 11.69      1.99  
12   AROW  3.83 14.68      1.01  
13  ARTNA  3.67 23.91      3.20  
14   ATNI  1.68  3.14      7.50  
15    ATO  2.97 18.59      1.72
```

2)  I can subset using conditions in function call itself, e.g.,

```
subset(data, PE <= 12 & Yield >=2.98)  

   Symbol Yield    PE DivGrowth  
11   ARLP   5.5 11.69      1.99
```

3)  However, if I put it as a character into a variable

```
divSelector<-c("PE <= 12 & Yield >=2.98")
```

4) and then subset using this variable; I get error as below

```
subset(data, divSelector)  
Error in subset.data.frame(data, divSelector) :   
  'subset' must evaluate to logical
```

5)  I've tried this sequence which works, i.e.,

```
ss<-expression(PE <= 12 & Yield >=2.98)  
subset(data, eval(ss))
```

6)  But the problem is that I cannot dynamically change the conditions in 'ss', e.g., I want to change `PE <= 12` to something depending on something else, say `PE <= threshold`, which is evaluated elsewhere.

7)  It looks like dynamic filter conditions give same error in selecting from just a straight vector!

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: The problem still is that I cannot setup a variable number of columns in some kind of vector and have this passed along.  In reality, there are something like 20 different columns and I want to use 6, or 8 or whatever.  All solutions force me to specify column names in function call parameters and I was looking for a way around that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, you'd like to dynamically edit your subset. You might want to try:

```
update_set <- function(PE, threshold, data, ...) {
    CONDITIONS <- expression(PE <= threshold)
    data[which(CONDITIONS),] # allows only the TRUE conditions, 
                             # will return your data object
}
```

This way you can call this function periodically, pass it variables in your context (or environment) then subset your data based on those requirements you are looking for. This should help get you started.

Comment: Thanx - I need to also include or exclude columns - ao I'll have to provide the proper expression.

Comment: you can have a secondary expression and insert that into the column space i.e. [(stuff),(here)]. At that point I might recommend the package data.table for these more complex subsetting routines.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
target.yield <- 2.98
target.PE <- 12
subset(data, PE <= target.PE & Yield >= target.yield)
```

Comment: Thanx that will work, but I also want to have a variable number of columns to select.  If not using colX say, I suppose could just say colX >= 0 to select all I guess.